# Prepare complex order into table record.(MS SQL)

Tags: sql-server

I have table like

**INPUT**

```
PKID  FKID IsActive OrderNo 
1      1    1       1
2      1    0       2
3      1    0       3
4      1    0       4
5      1    1       5
6      1    0       6
7      1    0       7
```

**OUTPUT**

```
PKID  FKID IsActive OrderNo OUTPUTs
1      1    1       1          1  (first IsActive True)
2      1    0       2          1   (After isActive true start from 1)
3      1    0       3          2
4      1    0       4          3
5      1    1       5          2   (Second IsActive True)
6      1    0       6          1   (After isActive true start from 1)
7      1    0       7          2
```

I have tried with `RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY IsActive ORDER BY orderNo)`
But not got same output.

MY Output logic

1) find rank by isActive

2) If isActive record is found then after that record start from 1

How can i got output in MS SQL?

Any other way, can i do it without rank?

THanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT PKID, FKID, IsActive, OrderNo,
       CASE 
          WHEN IsActive = 1 THEN grp 
          ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY OrderNo) - 1
       END AS Output
FROM (
  SELECT PKID, FKID, IsActive, OrderNo,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN IsActive = 1 THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY OrderNo) AS grp
  FROM mytable) AS t
```

**Note:** The query assumes that you are using SQL Server 2012, or later.